# expertPDF: change header height to match contents

Tags: pdf, header

I am using expertPDF to convert several HTML pages to pdf format.  Each page has different header and footer data but I want to use a single function for the output, so I would like to adjust the HeaderHeight to the size of the content and allow it to change for each page. The code would be something like:

```
 pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderHeight = newHeaderHeight;
```

where newHeaderHeight stores the height of the elements rendered in the header.

I've searched the documentation and there doesn't seem to be any way to do this that I can find - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I have an idea:

```
int numLines = headerText.Split('\n').Length;
pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderTextFontSize = 8;    
pdfConverter.PdfHeaderOptions.HeaderHeight = (numLines * 10) + 25;
//10 - because the line of text with font size - 8, has 2pt margins (I think)
//25 - constant distance independent of the number of lines header
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the short [tour]. Your post is not bad, as it goes, but please make sure to write answers *objectively*, which is what Stack Overflow aspires to be: a site where Questions and Answers can be found, and not a discussion forum. I've slightly edited it to remove what is known here as "fluff" :)